# Minka aire F749L ceiling fan starts then goes a few degrees and stops repeatedly for about a minute then stops altogether

Tags: ceiling-fan

Minka aire F749L ceiling fan was working yesterday, now starts then goes a few degrees and stops repeatedly for about a minute then stops altogether.

https://www.minkagroup.net/f749l-bn.html

Comment: did you change the battery on the remote

Comment: I installed one of these and remember an odd setting like "pulse" or something with just an icon  like that on the remote.  I pressed a speed setting  waited a few seconds and pressed "off"  It canceled the "pulse" type of action